# How to save a text file in Hard Disk using C#

Tags: c#, .net, io

I'm creating a logger for my app and I'm stuck with a problem I need to save my log file in my C drive but when I'm executing the Code its give me an error "Given Path Format Is Not Supported" My current code is given below

```
string path="C:\\Logger\\"+DateTime.Now.Date.ToString()+".txt";

    public void CreateDirectory()
    {
        if(!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path);
        }
    }
```

any solutions????

Comment: What Adel said is probably the key to finding the issue here. In general, if you encounter something like this, it would be helpful if you added the actual content of the variables. Have you tried debugging your code?

Comment: you can leave it to a framework such as Enterprise Library. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260157/whats-the-most-widely-used-logging-framework-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to have to format the date:

```
string path="C:\\Logger\\"+DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd")+".txt";
```

because the operating system isn't going to accept something like this:

```
C:\Logger\07/27/2013.txt
```

Now, for future reference, consider using `Path.Combine` to build your paths:

```
var path = Path.Combine("C:\\Logger",
    DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd"),
    ".txt");
```

You won't have to determine when to provide back slashes and when not to. If there isn't one, it will be appended for you.

Finally, you may experience problems if the directory doesn't exist. Something you can do to mitigate that is this:

```
var path = ...
var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

if (!Directory.Exists(dir))
{
    Directory.Create(dir);
}
```

But even then, you can run into permissions issues during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the result of this: `DateTime.Now.Date.ToString()` is accepted by the operating system.

Comment: I changed my file name to "C:\\Logger\\log.txt" but still not working

Comment: Nope I got This Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Logger\log.txt'

Comment: This error means the directory "Logger" is not found or you don't have permissions to it.

Comment: Actually I'm using Visual studio in admin mode still its not giving the permission to create the dir whats the reason behind this