# Notify the ActionBlock is completed to another class

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have written a method to implement TPL `ActionBlock`, which will do a function to find the XPath of the element I am Posting to the block. I am sending the element from a real-time application (whenever the user finds an element Post it to the block). Now, I want to check the block is completed or not when I call a save button from another class. The logic is if the `ActionBlok` is completed when we click the save button element will save with some save logic, otherwise show a message box not yet ready. For the first time, this idea is working, but from the second element onwards the `Actionblock` is not accepting any. I am using `block.Complete()` and `block.Completion.Wait()` for the save check. Now I can show I am calling the code/logic.

1. Once create an element, post it `ActionBlock`
   **Class1**

```
......
jobQ.Enqueue(familarizedElement);
......
```

2. Inside the `ActionBlock`
   **Class2**

```
public class TPLCommonDataFlow
{
    private ActionBlock<Element> _jobs;
    public static bool TPLFlowStatus = false;
    public static string JobStatus = string.Empty;
    public TPLCommonDataFlow()
    {
        var executionDataflowBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2,
        };

        _jobs = new ActionBlock<Element>((job) =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\Temp\\A.txt", "Started" + _jobs.InputCount.ToString());
            JobStatus = "started";
            Familiarization.FindAndUpdateXPath(job);
            File.WriteAllText("C:\\Temp\\A.txt", "Finished");
        }, executionDataflowBlockOptions);
        _jobs.Complete();


        //Wait for all messages to propagate through the network
        _jobs.Completion.Wait();

        //Checking all jobs are completed or not, if completed changing the boo, value.
        if (_jobs.InputCount == 0)
        {
            TPLFlowStatus = true;
            JobStatus = "stoped";
        }
    }
}
```

3. For the save I am checking the TPLFlowStatus boolean
   **Class3**

```
if (class2.TPLFlowStatus == true)
{
    //Save Logic
}
else
{
    //Message Box showing Not Ready
}
```

Now what I want is to check each time the job is completed or not for each element in the save logic. If the block having two elements in `Queue` and one is finished, then the `MessageBox` needs to popup once the save button pressed. If all completed in the block, then need to go to the save logic.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: It seems that you never [`Post`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1.post) anything to the `_jobs` block. Other than that it's not clear what you are trying to achieve. I noticed that the `TPLFlowStatus` and `JobStatus` properties are `static`, which doesn't make much sense. Also instead of logging with `File.WriteAllText`, I would suggest to switch to a [proper logging framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260157/whats-the-most-widely-used-logging-framework-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

The issue your seeing is that when a block is completed it will no longer accept new messages, you've told the block your done sending messages. To start sending a new batch of messages you can either keep the block alive by not calling complete and tracking the batch completion another way or you can just reset the block. A simple worker like this might be what you're looking for:

```
public class DataflowWorker
{
    private ActionBlock<string> _jobs;

    private void BuildJobsHandler()
    {
        _jobs = new ActionBlock<string>(x => Console.WriteLine(x) /*Do your work in the action block*/);
    }

    public async Task Enque(string element)
    {
        await _jobs.SendAsync(element);
    }

    public async Task CompleteJobsAndSave()
    {
        _jobs.Complete();
        await _jobs.Completion;
        //Save data when complete
        BuildJobsHandler();
    }
}
```